# Custom Helm Chart throws permission error in Open Shift cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, phpmyadmin, openshift, kubernetes-helm

Goal: I created a Helm chart called "phpmyadmin", which should deploy phpmyadmin to an Azure Open Shift cluster successfully.

Contents of the chart:

```
>> tree
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── clusterrole.yaml
│   ├── clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   └── serviceaccount.yaml
└── values.yaml

1 directory, 6 files
```

```
>> for file in templates/*; do cat $file; printf "\n"; done
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: system:openshift:scc:anyuid
rules: null

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-14T22:40:18Z"
  name: system:openshift:scc:anyuid
  resourceVersion: "892448651"
  uid: 7fb5ee9e-fe4e-4ddd-9e86-c7dae70ccd2c
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:openshift:scc:anyuid
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: phpmyadmin-sa
  namespace: phpmyadmin

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: phpmyadmin
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: phpmyadmin
  labels:
    app: phpmyadmin
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: phpmyadmin
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: phpmyadmin
  name: phpmyadmin
  namespace: phpmyadmin
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpmyadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: phpmyadmin
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: phpmyadmin
        resources: {}
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: phpmyadmin-sa
      serviceAccountName: phpmyadmin-sa

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-sa
  namespace: phpmyadmin
```

Expected results: After running `helm install phpmyadmin .` inside the chart directory the pod(s) should start running without errors.

Actual results: Running `helm install phpmyadmin ." results in failed pods:

```
>> oc get po -w
NAME                          READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-z4z7b   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          7s
phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-z4z7b   1/1     Running             0          9s
phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-z4z7b   0/1     Error               0          16s
phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-z4z7b   1/1     Running             1 (19s ago)   34s
phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-z4z7b   0/1     Error               1 (35s ago)   50s
```

These are the logs:

```
>> oc logs phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-z4z7b
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 5: /etc/phpmyadmin/config.secret.inc.php: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php': Permission denied
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.131.23.193. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

But when I run the following one or multiple times while letting some time pass (at least 90 seconds) the pod keeps running stable indefinitely without errors:

```
>> oc set sa deploy phpmyadmin phpmyadmin-sa -n phpmyadmin
deployment.apps/phpmyadmin serviceaccount updated
>> oc delete po phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-rtc2m 
pod "phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-rtc2m" deleted
>> oc get po -w
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
phpmyadmin-6fd55cbb86-dg22n   1/1     Running   0          6s
```

How can I make `helm install phpmyadmin .` work from the start without having to imperatively run `oc set`?

Note: I am using the clusterrole, clusterrolebinding and serviceaccount because I'm trying to remove the permission error.

Comment: I guess that you need to specify the port number like 8080 and user id which you expected.